# Java android google maps clustering , change icon in marker after click on them

Tags: java, android, google-maps

In my application I have a lot of points to show in google maps so I decided to use a ClusterManager. I want to change icon on one ClusterItem (which I clicked) it is any idea how I can do this :

I do this :

```
  @Override public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(this, mMap);

    final CustomClusterRenderer renderer = new CustomClusterRenderer(this, mMap, mClusterManager);

    mClusterManager.setRenderer(renderer);

    mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(
        new ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<StringClusterItem>() {
          @Override public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<StringClusterItem> cluster) {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Cluster click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
          }
        });

    mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(
        new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<StringClusterItem>() {
          @Override public boolean onClusterItemClick(StringClusterItem clusterItem) {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Cluster item click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
          }
        });

    mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener(
        new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener<StringClusterItem>() {
          @Override public void onClusterItemInfoWindowClick(StringClusterItem stringClusterItem) {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Clicked info window: " + stringClusterItem.title,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        });

    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(mClusterManager);
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(mClusterManager.getMarkerManager());
    mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      final LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-34 + i, 151 + i);
      mClusterManager.addItem(new StringClusterItem("Marker #" + (i + 1), latLng));
    }
      mClusterManager.addItem(new StringClusterItem("Marker #" + (10 + 1), new LatLng(-34+11 , 151 +11),true));

    mClusterManager.cluster();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/marker-clustering) they've mentioned **Customize the marker clusters**.

> The CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity defines its own cluster item, a
>   Person, and renders it by extending the DefaultClusterRenderer as
>   PersonRenderer.
>
> You can also implement `ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<Person>` in a similar way.

They've also provided [sample code](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/432007d5335c09d6911eca023ca7a415a6a70c4e/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity.java#L85) to change the icon/image of the ClusterItem.